# How to access an XML nth element's property value and attribute value

Tags: php, xml, echo

Good, I ask again for your help. I have an xml document (http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml) with several songs and I'm trying to create a code so that it can provide me each song individually xml document, but I'm getting find the right method to do with the code provides all the songs at the same time.

Example: I want to just take the music OLLY MURS - KISS ME, as is the 4 music I made this code:

```html
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
foreach($xml->Song as $item)
echo $item->Artist['name'][4] . " - " . $item['title'][4] ."<br>";
?>
```

but appears all the songs and I do not intend it, but rranjar one code that provides me the requested music. Can I help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the following code**

> Note that element position starts from 0, so if you want 4th element it is the 3rd index

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
$elementNo = 4;
$elepentPos = $elementNo - 1;
echo $xml->Song[$elepentPos]->Artist['name'] . ' --- ' . $xml->Song[$elepentPos]['title'];
```

> Now to describe this further
>
> Attributes are accessed using []
>
> Elements are accessed using object notation

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp follow this link to get more information

Comment: I will save this link to learn more about this topic on the code that you helped me was that he intended to once again thank you!

Comment: @Dharam Sorry to be a bother but I wanted to take also the function (Info StartTime), I tried to follow the methods that you utilizas you but without success. <?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
$elementNo = 3;
$elepentPos = $elementNo - 1;
echo $xml->Info->[$elepentPos]['StartTime'];
?> Can I help me?